# Unable to insert to multiple table rows to oracle(10g) database using for loop PHP

Tags: php, database, oracle10g

Unable to insert the multiple rows in the database while using the for loop, instead of inserting the multiple rows it will insert only the single row to the oracle DB.

After multiple time trying I'm unable to insert multiple rows in oracle database while using for loop(PHP), after spending a lot of time on search. I'm unable to find the solution of my problem. As far as I think there is some wrong with QUERY.

Moreover it will inserting the single row in the database,

My piece of code is given following

```
 $arr =array();

 for( $l=0; $l<count($_POST['i_id']); $l++ )
{

$item_id          = $_POST['i_id'][$l];
$fk_saleord_no    = $r;
$var2         = $_POST['sales_order_date'];
$fix2             = str_replace('/', '-', $var2);
$fk_saleord_date  =  date('d-m-Y', strtotime($fix2));
$entity_no_branch = $_POST['p_branch'];


$insert1 = "INSERT INTO SALE_ORDER_DTL(FK_SALEORD_NO, FK_SALEORD_DATE, 
ENTITY_NO_BRANCH, ITEM_ID )VALUES('.$fk_saleord_no.','. 
$fk_saleord_date.','. $entity_no_branch.','. $item_id .')";
$send1 = oci_parse($gerp, $insert1);
oci_execute($send1);

$arr[] = $insert1;
 }
```

On printing the my loop:

```
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($arr);
 exit;
```

It gives the following result:

```
Array
(
     [0] => INSERT INTO SALE_ORDER_DTL(FK_SALEORD_NO, FK_SALEORD_DATE, 
 ENTITY_NO_BRANCH, ITEM_ID )VALUES('.1190062.','. 11-01-2019.','. POS- 
 0001.','. 168 .')
     [1] => INSERT INTO SALE_ORDER_DTL(FK_SALEORD_NO, FK_SALEORD_DATE, 
 ENTITY_NO_BRANCH, ITEM_ID )VALUES('.1190062.','. 11-01-2019.','. POS- 
 0001.','. 191 .')
     [2] => INSERT INTO SALE_ORDER_DTL(FK_SALEORD_NO, FK_SALEORD_DATE, 
 ENTITY_NO_BRANCH, ITEM_ID )VALUES('.1190062.','. 11-01-2019.','. POS- 
 0001.','. 224 .')
 )
```

All I want is to insert all the rows to the database.

Comment: VALUES('.$fk_saleord_no.' must be VALUES(' ".$fk_saleord_no."

Comment: @Sfili_81 Thanks for respond. let me try this !

Comment: @Sfili_81 let me know single will placed on each value or over inside the value braces . ?

Answer (score 0):

> There is no need to concatenate in your query
>
> or use ".$fk_saleord_no." to call the parameter in query where you have used single ( ' ) use  ( " )

```
$arr =array();

 for( $l=0; $l<count($_POST['i_id']); $l++ )
{

$item_id          = $_POST['i_id'][$l];
$fk_saleord_no    = $r;
$var2         = $_POST['sales_order_date'];
$fix2             = str_replace('/', '-', $var2);
$fk_saleord_date  =  date('d-m-Y', strtotime($fix2));
$entity_no_branch = $_POST['p_branch'];


$insert1 = "INSERT INTO SALE_ORDER_DTL(FK_SALEORD_NO, FK_SALEORD_DATE, 
ENTITY_NO_BRANCH, ITEM_ID )VALUES('$fk_saleord_no',' 
$fk_saleord_date','$entity_no_branch',' $item_id ')";
$send1 = oci_parse($gerp, $insert1);
oci_execute($send1);

$arr[] = $insert1;
 }
```

Comment: Well, let me try check.

Comment: unable to insert a single row through this query. :(

Comment: any data inserted or not ??

Comment: no data inserted ! :( and yep I try with it but no data inserted !

Comment: check database connection it should  work  try passing static valur than check that data is inserting or not if not inserting means its database connection problem